# Create an action link with #id in .net core

Tags: html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to generate a link like this:

`http://localhost:5013/Home/Glossary#Agnikumara`

I **do not mean** the id on the resulting anchor tag, like:

`<a href="/home/glossary" id="Agnikumara">Link</a>`

I want the resulting link to be: `http://localhost:5013/Home/Glossary#Agnikumara` how do I do that in .NET Core MVC?

I keep searching, but I always get the thing that I don't want, i.e. an id on the actual anchor tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`asp-fragment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1#asp-fragment)

```html
<a asp-controller="Home"
   asp-action="Glossary"
   asp-fragment="Agnikumara">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you I had never heard of `asp-fragment` before. I had never it used either. Many thanks.